Is there a Slack setting, either user-facing or admin-facing, that causes inactive DMs to disappear after a period of inactivity?
One of my customers is looking for:

a setting where Slack direct messages that haven't been interacted with over X amount of days can disappear from my list


a setting where direct messages automatically are closed after (I used to have it as 5 days). I want read and unread messages to still be listed, unless I haven't interacted with them.

They're positive this setting existed at a former workplace but I get the feeling they're confusing this with an aggressive data retention policy.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
